# Stone topological Boolean algebras

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, set-theory, gn.general-topology, boolean-algebras

I am looking for an initial reference for a theorem which is known, namely:

> > ***Theorem***: A Boolean algebra $A$ admits a Stone space topology (i.e. is the underlying algebra of a Stone topological algebra) **iff** $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{P}(S)$, where $S$ is a set and a power-set $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is equiped with product topology.

The proposition can be found e.g. in book *Stone spaces* (**Corollary** in VI.3.2 *Stone-type dualities*  pp. 247 of 2002 edition) by P. Johnstone. I am going to cite it in a paper but it is given there without any reference on the original, initial proof, in a fashion of a folklore result.

I heаrd somewhere that it is Strauss theorem (but don't know which Strauss is it, is it Dona Strauss, may be not). Anyway I need to cite an author and paper.

Thanks for kindness and effort in advance.

**Edit:** Dave L Renfro pointed me to the paper of Dona Strauss where the following result is proven by means of Pontryagin duality.:

> > ***Theorem*:** If a Boolean algebra $A$ admits a  compact Hausdorff topology (i.e. is the underlying algebra of a compact Hausdorff topological algebra) then $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{P}(S)$ where   $S$ is a set and a power-set $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is equipped with product topology.

as well he pointed me to the paper of Guram Bezhanishvili and John Harding, where them provide simplified proof without use of Pontryagin duality. 
On that I remembered that I once even discussed the paper with John. 
Since the last result is enough for me, I accept the answer. Thank you   Dave L Renfro.

Comment: @YCor I'll edit post little bit.

Comment: Possibly the paper you want is: Dona Papert Strauss, [*Topological lattices*](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-18.2.217), **Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society** (3) 18 #2 (April 1968), 217-230. The paper is behind a paywall and I do not have access to it (without travelling to a nearby university library). However, Strauss' paper is cited in [*On the proof that compact Hausdorff Boolean algebras are powersets*](https://www.math.nmsu.edu/~jharding/2015%20Compact%20Hausdorff%20topological%20BAs.pdf) by Guram Bezhanishvili and John Harding, which is freely available.

Comment: Note that every compact Hausdorff topology on the underlying additive group of $A$ is totally disconnected, so "$A$ admits a Stone space topology" is equivalent to "$A$ has a topology of topological algebra that is compact Hausdorff".

Comment: Thanks for the question and answer! A few weeks ago I googled to see whether there's a notion of compact Boolean algebra with such a theorem and unfortunately this terminology "compact Boolean algebra" is used in another meaning. So I'm happy to have the answer now without even requesting it!

Comment: Pontryagin duality is something very standard and even easier to prove in this particular context (compact/discrete elementary abelian 2-groups). Is the original proof really more complicated?

Comment: @YCor I mean, that it is not necessary to use Pontryagin duality to prove the result, you can establish the proof with more simply tools.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and this is also what the authors of [BH] claim. It's just that I'm not convinced a priori that the proof is simpler just because it doesn't use Pontryagin duality. A proof can be made more complicated by avoiding a natural tool. This is why I'm curious to know more about Strauss' proof (to which I don't have access either).

Comment: @YCor I sent to you copies. If you didn't  received them let me know.

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov thanks! I have a definite opinion then. Strauss' original proof is elegant far simpler than the more recent technical [BH], and it is not serious in [BH] to claim that Strauss' proof relies on the "considerable machinery of Pontryagin duality". It only relies on the fact that if $A$ is an abelian compact topological group with $2A=0$, then for every $0\neq a\in A$ there exists a continuous homomorphism $f:A\to\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ such that $f(a)\neq 0$. This is something standard and far less than the whole machinery of Pontryagin duality (which is not that considerable!).

Comment: That said, it does not mean that the more complicated (and possibly more elementary) proof in [BH] is not interesting. There are results for which people made effort to find a choice-free proof, often more complicated, but which can be useful to get "constructive versions". I don't know this yields something of this kind, but the methods of [BH] (which goes through Fourier transform within finite Boolean subalgebras) let me suspect that it could provide something of this kind, which is however not reflected in the stated theorem.

Comment: PS the Peter-Weyl theorem was published in 1927, 7 years before Pontryagin established his duality, and is enough to prove the necessary lemma (of my previous comment, on compact abelian groups $A$ with $2A=0$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the paper you want is

Dona Papert Strauss, [*Topological lattices*](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-18.2.217), **Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society** (3) 18 #2 (April 1968), 217-230.

Strauss' paper is behind a paywall and I do not have access to it, without travelling to a nearby university library. However, Strauss' paper is cited, for the result I think you are asking about, in the following paper, and a copy of the following paper [is freely available at John Harding's web page](https://www.math.nmsu.edu/~jharding/2015%20Compact%20Hausdorff%20topological%20BAs.pdf).

Guram Bezhanishvili and John Harding, [*On the proof that compact Hausdorff Boolean algebras are powersets*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11083-015-9363-y), **Order** 33 #2 (July 2016), 263-268.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll see a papers you mentioned (fortunately I am free to use sci-hub.tw to avoid paywalls), I'll ask Guram and John too. If it is the case that the result is in there I'll accept your answer. Thanks one more time.